# How to get the current context?

Tags: android

I want to use it in my array adapter. When I put `this` in a sub-activity to create an adapter it does not work.

Answer (score 37):

[`getApplicationContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) can get the context value

Comment: This returns application context, not the current context, both are different.

Answer (score 33):

You can get context a few ways:

By the Activity, using `Your_Activity_Name.this`

By the application, using `getApplicationContext()`

By the View, using `Your_View.getContext()`

The only one I would not recommend is using `getBaseContext()`. If you need something universal, have a public static variable in your main activity and assign the application context to it when your app starts. This way you can always call `Your_Activity.your_context_variable`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getBaseContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext%28%29) but this is [`not a local context`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458211/461982).

Answer (score 2):

Besides the correct previous answers, you may want to think about refactoring your code if you've come to the point where you need to access "your" context from a sub activity.
When you create a sub activity (ie: startActivityForResult) you are truly waiting for a result, not for an action in the caller activity. Then, when the sub activity has finished (and you have the result of its calculations), you can access your context in a proper way.
It just doesn't seem fine that the subactivity is aware of its creator, not to mention interact with it.