# What's up with different contexts in android?

Tags: android, this, android-context

What's the difference between myClass.this and getBaseContext?  When I put an AlertDialog in a different class and instantiate it, I can only get the dialog to show if I use myClass.this from the parent class.  I thought getBaseContext() did the same thing but I guess not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should look here first: [Diffinitive rules for using Android's getBaseContext, getApplicationContext or using an Activity's “this”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458156/diffinitive-rules-for-using-androids-getbasecontext-getapplicationcontext-or-us)

Answer (score 0):

"this" refers to what method you're in, and "getBaseContext/getApplicationContext" refers to the Activity you're in.

Comment: this refers to class/object you are in, not method.