# How to get the information about sent sms?

Tags: android, sms

In my application i am getting recieved messages by using brodcast reacevers.

but i want to get the details about sent message information also.

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906135/how-to-get-sent-sms-list

Comment: what kind of details do you mean here.... delivery details or message details...??

Comment: i want message details like.mobile no,message to whom to send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do (if you have to!) is poll the SMS content provider (content://sms/sent) periodically and remember which messages you see.

Comment: if u don't mind please give some example

Comment: First try to search on net & the ask for it

Comment: i am searching for this till from morning