# how to intercept outgoing SMS in Android?

Tags: android, sms

Please help me in finding the solution for **intercepting SMS** after selecting **native App** from **Chooser** while **sending SMS**, I have done R&D for this problem and found that we can't intercept **outgoing SMS** at that time after selecting **native App** from **Chooser**.

So if anyone have experience regarding this issue then please share it and it would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: What R&D you did yet, Share some of your finding??

Comment: Try the solution Cristian gave: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5808648/1479570

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from the application's perspective because the sending of the SMS is controlled by the SMSManager that interacts with the Framework dealing with the sending at the Telephony level, which is **NOT** accessible by an application layer.

However; you can access the data in the database using one of the supplied comment's suggestions.