# Log outgoing SMS messages on Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listen to outgoing SMS or sent box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808577/listen-to-outgoing-sms-or-sent-box)

Is it possible to intercept outgoing SMS messages in Android. I know it's trivial to receive SMS and send it directly but can an outgoing message (for example, from the default message app or from another possibly malicious app) be detected, intercepted or logged? All I need is a simple log message with the outgoing number and message; I do not need to modify the message.

Uses for this are both legitimate (monitor apps that are sending SMSs) and shady (spy on outgoing messages). I'm going for the former and not the latter :)

Answer (score 4):

```
For **monitoring sms** state in/out you have **create class** like this 
and **start service** for **monitoring**

public class SMSMonitor 
{
    private ServiceController mainActivity;
   private ContentResolver contentResolver = null;
   private Handler smshandler = null;
   private ContentObserver smsObserver = null;
   public String smsNumber enter code here= "";
   public static boolean thCountStatus = false;
   public static int thIncreCount = 0;
   public boolean monitorStatus = false;
   String code;
//   Feedmanager fm = null;
   static public String activationCode;
   int smsCount = 0;

   public SMSMonitor(final ServiceController mainActivity, final Context mainContext) {
      this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
      contentResolver = mainActivity.getContentResolver();
      smshandler = new SMSHandler();
      smsObserver = new SMSObserver(smshandler);
   }

   public void startSMSMonitoring() {
      try {
         monitorStatus = false;
         if (!monitorStatus) {
            contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri
                  .parse("content://sms"), true, smsObserver);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d("test","SMSMonitor :: startSMSMonitoring Exception == "+ e.getMessage());
      }
   }

   public void stopSMSMonitoring() {
      try {
         monitorStatus = false;
         if (!monitorStatus) {
            contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(smsObserver);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("test","SMSMonitor :: stopSMSMonitoring Exception == "+ e.getMessage());
      }
   }

   class SMSHandler extends Handler {
      public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
      }
   }

   class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver {
      private Handler sms_handle = null;
      public SMSObserver(final Handler smshandle) {
         super(smshandle);
         sms_handle = smshandle;
      }

      public void onChange(final boolean bSelfChange) {
         super.onChange(bSelfChange);
         Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
               try {
                  monitorStatus = true;

                  // Send message to Activity
                  Message msg = new Message();
                  sms_handle.sendMessage(msg);
                  Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
                  Cursor cur = mainActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                        uriSMSURI, null, null, null, "_id");

                  if (cur.getCount() != smsCount) {
                     smsCount = cur.getCount();

                     if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
                        cur.moveToLast();
                        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++) 
                        {
                           //Log("KidSafe","SMSMonitor :: incoming Column Name : " +
                              //cur.getColumnName(i));
                              //cur.getString(i));
                        }

                        smsNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
                        if (smsNumber == null || smsNumber.length() <= 0)
                        {
                           smsNumber = "Unknown";

                        }

                        int type = Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type")));
                        String message = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
                        Log.d("test","SMSMonitor :: SMS type == " + type);
                        Log.d("test","SMSMonitor :: Message Txt == " + message);
                        Log.d("test","SMSMonitor :: Phone Number == " + smsNumber);

                        cur.close();

                        if (type == 1) {
                           onSMSReceive(message, smsNumber);
                        } else {
                           onSMSSend(message, smsNumber);
                        }
                     }
                  }
                  /*if (cur.getCount() < smsCount) {
                     Log("KidSafe","SMS Count last:: " + smsCount);
                     Log("KidSafe","SMS cur Count last:: " + cur.getCount());
                     smsCount = cur.getCount();
                     Log("KidSafe","SMS Count last:: " + smsCount);
                  }*/
               } catch (Exception e) {
//                  Log("KidSafe","SMSMonitor :: onChange Exception == "+ e.getMessage());
               }
            }
         };
         thread.start();
      }

      private void onSMSReceive(final String message, final String number) {
         synchronized (this) {
             Log.d("test", "In OnSmsReceive");
            Log.d("test", "Message"+message);
                               Log.d("Sample", "Number"+number);
         }
      }

      private void onSMSSend(final String message, final String number) {
         synchronized (this) {
             Log.d("test", "In OnSmsSend");
            Log.d("test", "Message"+message);
                               Log.d("Sample", "Number"+number);
         }
      }
   }
}

//for starting monitor create a service like below
public class ServiceController extends Service
{
   private Activity mainActivity;
   SMSMonitor sms;

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

      return null;
   }

   public void onCreate() 
   {
      super.onCreate();

      /**** Start Listen to Outgoing SMS ****/
      Log.d("test","###### ServiceController :: CallSMS Monitor method ######");
      sms = new SMSMonitor(this , mainActivity);
      sms.startSMSMonitoring();
   }

   @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        /**** Stop Listen to Outgoing SMS ****/
        Log.d("test","###### ServiceController :: StopSMS Monitor method ######");
        sms.stopSMSMonitoring();
    }
}
```

Comment: @NaeemA.Malik how did you start this, I dont have activity? Should I start it on boot?

Comment: It's been a long time but I guess I used this concept in a Broadcast Receiver class somehow...