# Android: How do i trigger an app on an event?

Tags: android

Suppose I want to start an app to run in background as soon as an event occurs in the phone.

For example:-

1. When I open my gallery I may want to automatically start my app which monitors my file browsing and prepares database for most recent documents, most listened song, etc and is automatically closed when I exit my gallery folder.
2. Whenever I open my internet browser I might want to start my app in background, which monitors how many times I visited a particular site and it automatically closes when I close the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, and i'm not talking about remote launch app, but capture events of other apps like Gallery or Browser.

If this are only hipotetic examples, you should show a real examples because i think collect this type of data will be more painful problem than trigger app on an event due a lot of security reasons.

Comment: Personally I'ld like to start an app when a text message is been sent from the mobile. Is this possible or not?

Comment: Apparently yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808577/listen-to-outgoing-sms-or-sent-box

Comment: Thanx mate; now I get when and where, what can be used ;)