# Intercept Outgoing SMS in Android

Tags: android, encryption, sms

I am looking to write an automatically encrypting/decrypting sms/mms app for android. The idea to to encrypt the message and send it where it is decryption on the receiving phone.

While it is easy to automatically decrypt a message on receive, you just decrypy it, delete it, and add it again. It seems difficult to intercept a message as it is being sent and change it.

Is there anyway to read and edit a text message that is being sent right before the phone actually sends it. Thus the sending and receiving phone could have the decryption keys on them and never actually have to deal with using a different app or manual encryption, the phones would just automatically do it.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a **`ContentObserver`** on your sent messages to intercept any outgoing sms.

```
ContentResolver mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/out"),true, mObserver);
```

Use **`Cursor`** to go to any sms and extract the body of the SMS.

Use something like

```
Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/out");
Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(smsUri, null, null, null, null);
mCursor.moveToNext();
mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
```

And have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808577/listen-to-outgoing-sms-or-sent-box)..it answers your problem elaborately.

Comment: Thanks a lot..
I l reach you if face any further probz..
Can i get a tutorial about cursors n Content resolver..
Actually im naive n understood the above code partially..

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial in that case : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: And dont forget to **upvote/accept** my answer if it was of any help! Cheers! :)

Comment: Ofcorz.. diz is my first query.. definitely once i gain repttn

Comment: That would simply be great! :)