# Listening to outgoing sms not working android

Tags: java, android, sms, contentobserver

I am trying to listen to outgoing sms messages. I was following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808577/listen-to-outgoing-sms-or-sent-box) but it is not working. I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I am no familiar at all with Content Observers so forgive my ignorance.

I wanted to create it in a service so it would be running all the time. here is my code in that service:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsOutgoingObserver extends Service {
    public SmsOutgoingObserver() {
    }
    /* this method handles a single incoming request */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int id) {

        Log.d("OUTGOING", "RUNNING SERVICE");

        return START_STICKY; // stay running
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null; // disable binding
    }

    public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public SmsObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);

            Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/out");
            Cursor cr = SmsOutgoingObserver.this.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

            cr.moveToNext();
            String address = cur.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("body"));

            Log.d("OUTGOING", address);

            cr.close();

            //Database.messageReceived(SmsOutgoingObserver.this, address);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the silly mistake on my part that @CommonsWare pointed out, me missing

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/out"),true, new SmsObserver(new Handler()));
}
```

the other issue was actually in these two lines

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content:&‌​#47;/sms/out‌​"),true, new SmsObserver(new Handler()));
```

and

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/out");
```

where I changed the `content://sms/out` to `content://sms` and then proceeded to check for the type to make sure the change I was getting was actually an outgoing message. I also had to make sure to check for multiple calls like so:

```
if (cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("type")) == 2) {
    if(id != cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(cr.getColumnName(0)))) {
        id = cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(cr.getColumnName(0)));

        String address = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("address"));
        Database.messageSent(SmsOutgoingObserver.this, address);
            Log.d("OUTGOING", address);
        } else {
            Log.d("OUTGOING", "MESSAGE ALREADY LOGGED");
        }
     };
}
```

and simply defined `private int id = 0;` as a global variable

Answer (score 1):

Your `SmsOutgoingObserver` does nothing other than log a message to LogCat. If you want to use `SmsObserver`, you need to add some code, such as call `registerContentObserver()`. This is shown in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5808648/115145) on the question that you linked to.

Comment: I had it in there before I must have erased it accidentally and not realized it I will give it a shot

Comment: @SantiGallego: Having that code in `onCreate()` should work. Note that SMSes do not have to be written to that `ContentProvider`, and that many users may be very irritated with you for trying to have a service run continuously. Google has also hinted that this sort of service may be eliminated in the future. On Android 7.0+, you can use `JobScheduler` to monitor a `ContentProvider` without having to have a service run continuously -- see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/JobScheduler) that monitors `ContactsContract`.